# XML data to tables using PHP with multiple elements, output should be based on the number of X elements

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

my xml looks likes this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<personnel>
                <person id='1'>
                                <person_name>John</person_name>
                                <person_lastname>Doe</person_lastname>
                                <codes>
                                         <code_number>A132</code_number>
                                         <code_number>B123</code_number>
                                         <code_number>C123</code_number>
                                </codes>
                                <person_code>
                                <code_title>Developer</requisition_title>
                                <code_relocation>15~25%</code_relocation>
                                </person_code>
                </person>
             
</personnel>
```

i wanted to make a table(using PHP) which rows are dependent by the number of "code_number" under "codes". so that the table should look like this:

```
Person ID | Person Name| Person LastName | Code Numbers 
_________________________________________________________
         1|        John|              Doe|        A123
_________________________________________________________
         1|        John|              Doe|        B123
_________________________________________________________
         1|        John|              Doe|        C123
```

my currrent PHP script which i got from other stackoverflow examples is:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('person.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

echo <<<EOF <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">   <tr>
    <th>Person ID</th>
    <th>Person Name</th>
    <th>Person LastName </th>
    <th>Code Numbers</th>
    </tr>
EOF;

$persons = $xpath->evaluate('//person');
foreach ($persons as $person) {
   echo '<tr>', "\n";
   echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./id)', $person)), '</td>', "\n";
   echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./person_name)', $person)), '</td>', "\n";
   echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./person_lastname)', $person)), '</td>', "\n";
   $codes = array();
   foreach ($xpath->evaluate('./codes/code_number', $person) as $code_number) {
       $codes[] = $code_number->nodeValue;
   }
   echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars(implode(', ', $codes)).'</td>', "\n";
   echo '</tr>', "\n"; } echo '</table>';

?>
```

however the output of this is based on how many "person id" is on the XML file.
thanks for you help!

Comment: also i cant get the PERSON ID inside the xpath if i use this:

`code`echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./id)', $person)), '</td>', "\n";`code`

Comment: For future reference, use the code formatting for code using the `{}` button. Don't put code in a block quote, it's impossible to read and difficult to recover.

Comment: thanks @alexander. will do use the {} button next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 1 row per `<codes>` per `<person>`, then you need to loop through the `<codes>` inside the `<person>`. To get the `<person>` `id` use `->getAttribute('id')` -

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('person.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

echo <<<EOF
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">   <tr>
    <th>Person ID</th>
    <th>Person Name</th>
    <th>Person LastName </th>
    <th>Code Numbers</th>
    </tr>
EOF;

$persons = $xpath->evaluate('//person');
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    //loop through each <code_number>
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('./codes/code_number', $person) as $code_number) {
        echo '<tr>', "\n";
        echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($person->getAttribute('id')), '</td>', "\n";
        echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./person_name)', $person)), '</td>', "\n";
        echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($xpath->evaluate('string(./person_lastname)', $person)), '</td>', "\n";
        echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($code_number->nodeValue).'</td>', "\n";
        echo '</tr>', "\n"; 
    }
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

This results in

[image]

Comment: this worked flawlessly! i saw the foreach for code_number as nodeValue i was missing and wasnt able to pull thru.